# .htaccess Problem to remove extensions creates subdirectory problem

Tags: .htaccess

I have a static html website and I am using the following code to remove the .html extension for SEO reasons:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Problem is when I add a subdirectory /blog/ I get a 403 Forbidden error. Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you were missing the html condition.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```